Can someone help me with google chrome error showing profile in use?
The error message is as follows,

terminal-dogma@banshee:~/Softwares$ google-chrome
[37887:37887:0808/165922.595508:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(353)] 
The profile appears to be in use by another Google Chrome process (3153) on another computer (terminal-dogma-Aspire-A715-75G).  
Chrome has locked the profile so that it doesn't get corrupted.  
If you are sure no other processes are using this profile, you can unlock the profile and relaunch Chrome.
[37887:37887:0808/165922.595584:ERROR:message_box_dialog.cc(144)] 
Unable to show a dialog outside the UI thread message loop: Google Chrome 
- The profile appears to be in use by another Google Chrome process (3153) on another computer (terminal-dogma-Aspire-A715-75G).  
Chrome has locked the profile so that it doesn't get corrupted.  
If you are sure no other processes are using this profile, you can unlock the profile and relaunch Chrome.


what help do you require? ... did you read the message?

Its whenever I am installing chrome, after clicking on the app it isn't starting, and whenever I am trying to open from terminal I am getting the prior mentioned message. How to troubleshoot it?
